# How to run grails integration tests with gradle

Tags: gradle, grails

Old internal-tools.gradle

```
description = 'Internal Tools'

ext {
    grailsVersion = "2.4.4"
}
apply plugin: "grails"

grails {
    grailsVersion = "2.4.4"
    springLoadedVersion = '1.2.4.RELEASE'
}

configurations.all {
    // already provided by the JVM, Grails complains if classes show up twice in the classpath
    exclude group: 'xml-apis', module: 'xml-apis'

    exclude module: 'grails-plugin-log4j'

    //provided servlet container
    exclude group: 'javax.el', module: 'el-api'
    exclude group: 'org.glassfish.web', module: 'el-impl'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':business-logic')
    test(project(path: ':business-logic', configuration: 'testArtifacts'))

    def slf4jVersion = '1.7.2'
    compile "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:${slf4jVersion}"
    compile "org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:${slf4jVersion}"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:${slf4jVersion}"


    // We force a newer version of Ant to work around a bug in the Oracle JRE.  This can be removed when Grails upgrades Ant
    // See Ant 'Bug 54641' for more details
    runtime "org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.2"
    runtime "org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.9.2"

    // Grails
    runtime "org.grails:grails-dependencies:$grailsVersion"

    // Grails plugins
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.6.1"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.55"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:export:1.6"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:webflow:2.1.0"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:logback:0.3.1'
    runtime "org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:$grailsVersion"

    test "org.grails:grails-test:$grailsVersion"
    test "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing:$grailsVersion"
    test 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.1'
    test 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.8.0'
    test 'nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.6.2'

    bootstrap 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'
}

test {
    doFirst {
        tasks.getByPath(':dbTestCreate').ext.testDatabase.create()
    }

    dependsOn(':configProperties')
    jvmOptions.jvmArgs '-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m'
    jvmOptions.systemProperty('XXXX.conf.file', "$configOutputDir/XXXX_test.properties")
    String protocol = "file:"
    jvmOptions.systemProperty 'logback.configurationFile', protocol + new File(rootProject.projectDir,"dev/log/logback.xml").getAbsolutePath()
}

'grails-run-app' {
    dependsOn(':configProperties', ':dbValidate')
    jvmOptions.jvmArgs '-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m'
    jvmOptions.systemProperty('XXXX.conf.file', "$configOutputDir/XXXX_dev.properties")
    String protocol = "file:"
    jvmOptions.systemProperty 'logback.configurationFile', protocol + new File(rootProject.projectDir,"dev/log/logback.xml").getAbsolutePath()
}

war {
    String protocol = "file:"
    jvmOptions.systemProperty 'logback.configurationFile', protocol + new File(rootProject.projectDir,"dev/log/logback.xml").getAbsolutePath()
}

// We re-package the war so it will include the extra GradleCM meta-info.
// We use a zip task rather than a war task because the war task adds extra files such as a second web.xml
task reWar(type: Zip, dependsOn: ['war']) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/libs")
    extension = 'war'
    // HACK: the input needs to be wrapped in a closure so it is evaluated lazily. This is because the 'war' task output
    // file changes once the version is set
    from { zipTree(war.outputFile) }

    //
    // Build info file
    //
    from (rootProject.buildinfo.filedir) {
        include rootProject.buildinfo.filename
        into 'META-INF'
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives reWar
}

// Ensure tests are run for uploadArchives
uploadArchives.dependsOn('check')

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://nexus.XXXXX.com/content/groups/public/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:2.1.2"
    }
}
```

New internal-tools.gradle

```
description = 'Internal Tools'

ext {
    grailsVersion = "3.3.3"
}
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"

grails {
    grailsVersion = "3.3.3"
    //springLoadedVersion = '1.2.4.RELEASE'
}

configurations.all {
    // already provided by the JVM, Grails complains if classes show up twice in the classpath
    exclude group: 'xml-apis', module: 'xml-apis'

    exclude module: 'grails-plugin-log4j'

    //provided servlet container
    exclude group: 'javax.el', module: 'el-api'
    exclude group: 'org.glassfish.web', module: 'el-impl'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':business-logic')
    //test(project(path: ':business-logic', configuration: 'testArtifacts'))

    def slf4jVersion = '1.7.2'
    compile "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:${slf4jVersion}"
    compile "org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:${slf4jVersion}"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:${slf4jVersion}"


    // We force a newer version of Ant to work around a bug in the Oracle JRE.  This can be removed when Grails upgrades Ant
    // See Ant 'Bug 54641' for more details
    runtime "org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.2"
    runtime "org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.9.2"

    // Grails
    runtime "org.grails:grails-dependencies:$grailsVersion"

    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:3.3.3"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:converters:4.0.0'

    compile 'org.grails.plugins:gorm-tools:6.1.11-v.12'

    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"



    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"





    compile "org.grails:grails-core"

    // Grails plugins
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.6.1"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.55"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:export:1.6"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:webflow:2.1.0"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:logback:0.3.1'
    runtime "org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:$grailsVersion"

    //test "org.grails:grails-test:$grailsVersion"
   // test "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing:$grailsVersion"
   // test 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.1'
    //test 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.8.0'
   // test 'nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.6.2'

   // bootstrap 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'
}

test {
    doFirst {
        tasks.getByPath(':dbTestCreate').ext.testDatabase.create()
    }

    dependsOn(':configProperties')
    jvmArgs '-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m'
    systemProperty 'XXXX.conf.file', "$configOutputDir/XXXX_test.properties"
    String protocol = "file:"
    systemProperty 'logback.configurationFile', protocol + new File(rootProject.projectDir,"dev/log/logback.xml").getAbsolutePath()
}

bootRun {
    dependsOn(':configProperties', ':dbValidate')
    jvmArgs '-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m'
    systemProperty 'XXXX.conf.file', "$configOutputDir/XXXX_dev.properties"
    String protocol = "file:"
    systemProperty 'logback.configurationFile', protocol + new File(rootProject.projectDir,"dev/log/logback.xml").getAbsolutePath()
}

war {
    String protocol = "file:"
    //systemProperty 'logback.configurationFile', protocol + new File(rootProject.projectDir,"dev/log/logback.xml").getAbsolutePath()
}

// We re-package the war so it will include the extra GradleCM meta-info.
// We use a zip task rather than a war task because the war task adds extra files such as a second web.xml
task reWar(type: Zip, dependsOn: ['war']) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/libs")

    extension = 'war'
    // HACK: the input needs to be wrapped in a closure so it is evaluated lazily. This is because the 'war' task output
    // file changes once the version is set
    from { zipTree(war.archivePath) }

    //
    // Build info file
    //
    from (rootProject.buildinfo.filedir) {
        include rootProject.buildinfo.filename
        into 'META-INF'
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives reWar
}

// Ensure tests are run for uploadArchives
uploadArchives.dependsOn('check')

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/jfrog/jfrog-jars/" }
        maven { url "https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases-local/" }
        //maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/" }
        maven { url "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/" }
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:3.3.3"
        classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.+"
        classpath "org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:5.+"
        classpath "org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.+"
        //classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
    }
}
```

I had to upgrade gradle from 2.2 to 3.5.  One of the gradle modules I have is a grails app called internal-tools.  I posted the old build.gradle we used and the new one I am still working on.  I had to change some of it around after upgrading gradle to 3.5.

The old internal-tools.gradle used to start up the application and run through a series of integration tests.  My new internal-tools.gradle is not starting up the application and running through the integration tests.  I was wondering if anyone had any ideas or ran into the same problem upgrading gradle and grails.  I inherited this project so I'm not 100% sure what these gradle files are doing.

If the 'grails-run-app' task is what started it up in the old gradle file what is the equivalent I can use in gradle 3.5?  I tried putting the same things in a "bootRun" task but that doesn't seem to work.  It could be related to an issue I was having where the app thought it was spring boot so I had to stick a public static void main in there so the ":internal-tools:findMainClass" would work.

Actually the more I look at it I think the grails-run-app was just used to start up the application after it was built.  So I'm not sure what started up the application and ran the integration tests in the old gradle file, and how I can reproduce the same thing with gradle 3.5

Comment: Was it this dependency that did it all in gradle 2.2 and grails 2.4.4?  If so how can I do the same thing with gradle 3.5 and grails 3.3.3?
```
test "org.grails:grails-test:$grailsVersion"
test "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing:$grailsVersion"
```

Comment: When I uncomment these lines it fails with Could not find method test() for arguments [org.grails:grails-test:3.3.3]

test "org.grails:grails-test:$grailsVersion"
 test "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing:$grailsVersion"